# Running a docker-compose "Getting Started" example causes "Invalid volume specification" on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am absolutely new to Docker. I followed steps described in Docker Compose's ["Getting Started" tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/):

1. Install Docker Toolbox
2. Start Docker Quickstart Terminal
3. Add project files
4. Run `docker-compose up` command

And I got following error:

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: Invalid bind mount spec "D:\\Projects\\composetest:/code:rw": Invalid volume specification: 'D:\Projects\composetest:/code:rw'
[31mERROR[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code:rw
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Project structure:

```
D:\Projects\composetest
  ├── app.py
  ├── docker-compose.yml
  ├── Dockerfile
  └── requirements.txt
```

My configuration:

1. Windows 10 Single Language
2. Docker Toolbox 1.12.5

Why does it happen? Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was I didn't set the environment variable `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS`. It is described in the [CLI variables doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/).

So, if this problem exists, you should create new Windows environment variable called `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` and set it to `1`. Or you can create `.env` file in the path `docker-compose.yml` is placed with following content:

```
 COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

It will solve this problem.