# Docker volumes MariaDB Windows

Tags: docker, mariadb, docker-compose

I am trying to Dockerize and Open Source a project I created in second year of college, this project uses MariaDB, phpMyAdmin and PHP/Yii Framework.

My objective is to make it ready to go using only a simple
`docker-compose up`
command.

I managed to get the connection between phpMyAdmin and the DB working and now I am stuck on trying to get Docker to have a relative path to a database volume, to make it consistent.

Here is what I have regarding the volume mounting:

```
volumes:
  - './database/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql'
```

This is storing the database files inside the project and then I can ignore those files in `.gitignore`
The problem is when I run `docker-compose up` with this configuration I get:

`Invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\MySelf\coding\my_app\database\mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw'`

Regarding the host, I am using a Windows with Docker Toolbox but I want the `docker-compose.yml` to work regardless of the OS.

I have seen other questions similar but their error came from problems with absolute paths on Windows which I am not looking for.

**EDIT: Adding the correct final docker-compose.yml, hopefully it can help**

```
version: '2'
services:
  web_db:
    build: ./database/mysql
    command: "mysqld --innodb-buffer-pool-size=20M"
    volumes:
      - ./database/mysql/data/:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database/mysql/initDB/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'YOURPASSWORD'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'support-technique'
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '172.17.0.1'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    container_name: web_db

  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - web_db
    links:
      - web_db:db
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - web_db
    links:
      - web_db:mysql
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    environment:
PMA_HOST: mysql
```

Comment: But `/var/lib/mysql` it's a Linux path!

Comment: @Hackerman `/var/lib/mysql` is the path in the Docker container not on my host machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you [Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume), the documentation says:

> The `host-dir` can either be an absolute path or a name value. If you supply an absolute path for the `host-dir`, Docker bind-mounts to the path you specify. If you supply a name, Docker creates a named volume by that name.
>
> A name value must start with an alphanumeric character, followed by `a-z0-9`, `_` (underscore), `.` (period) or `-` (hyphen).
> An absolute path starts with a `/` (forward slash).

That explain the error message.

Using an absolute path [links it to the OS](https://superuser.com/a/1054437/141) (which is not what you want)

```
docker run -v c:\<path>:/c:\<container path>
docker run -v /c/<path>:/c:\<container path>
```

As mentioned in "[Running a docker-compose “Getting Started” example causes “Invalid volume specification” on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41320171/6309)", try first setting this [docker-compose environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#/composeconvertwindowspaths):

> Create `.env` file in the path docker-compose.yml is placed with following content:

```
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

The [OP Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4884034/daniel) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343972/docker-volumes-mariadb-windows/41382347?noredirect=1#comment69971441_41382347) that **with the `.env` including `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS`, a relative path works**.

I would recommend using a **[data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/data-volumes)** name instead: it won't depend on an host pathname.

Comment: So relative paths are not an option at all ?

Comment: @Daniel Exactly: for the host, no relative path: absolute path or vaolume name only.

Comment: actually relative paths work! I just needed to follow your suggestion and add the `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` to .env! Can you update your answer so I can give you the bounty?

Comment: @Daniel Great. I have edited the answer to make your conclusion more visible.