# Docker-compose inavalid volume specification and server name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to prepare my image but I have got problem with volume and server name. I attached cmd and all my code.

```
catalog structure
docker-compose
main
    Dockerfile
    content
        otherFiles
        sharedDataOutput
        sharedDataInput
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY content ./
```

DockerCompose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  webapp:  
    container_name: My_Server_1
    build: main/.
    volumes:
       - .\sharedDataInput:\sharedDataInput
       - .\sharedDataOutput:\sharedDataOutput
    ports:
       - "8200:80"
```

cmd

```
C:\Fun\Docker\ContainerDockerCompose>Docker-compose up --build
Building webapp
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/aspnet
 ---> 823ecde59414
Step 2/4 : RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 590c945d1ae9
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ce618992985c
Step 4/4 : COPY content ./
 ---> 63e0137b4954

Successfully built 63e0137b4954
Successfully tagged containerdockercompose_webapp:latest
Creating My_Server_1 ... error

ERROR: for CDS_Server_1  Cannot create container for service webapp: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Fun\Docker\ContainerDockerCompose\sharedDataOutput:/sharedDataOutput:rw'

ERROR: for webapp  Cannot create container for service webapp: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Fun\Docker\ContainerDockerCompose\sharedDataOutput:/sharedDataOutput:rw'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**I try this files access**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY content ./
RUN icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\* /grant Everyone:F
```

and still not work (also added this
[Running a docker-compose "Getting Started" example causes "Invalid volume specification" on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318252/running-a-docker-compose-getting-started-example-causes-invalid-volume-specif) )

```
C:\Fun\Docker\ContainerDockerCompose>docker-compose up --build
Building webapp
Step 1/5 : FROM microsoft/aspnet
 ---> 823ecde59414
Step 2/5 : RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c11df3b75cf4
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8973084866b3
Step 4/5 : COPY content ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 014e59f2e51b
Step 5/5 : RUN icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\* /grant Everyone:F
 ---> Running in f186b9025583
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Access
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Areas
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\favicon.ico
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fonts
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Global.asax
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Scripts
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sharedDataInput
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sharedDataOutput
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Web.config
processed file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WinForms
Successfully processed 13 files; Failed processing 0 files
Removing intermediate container f186b9025583
 ---> 4d16de798fb3

Successfully built 4d16de798fb3
Successfully tagged containerdockercompose_webapp:latest
Creating CDS_Server_1 ... error

ERROR: for CDS_Server_1  Cannot create container for service webapp: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Fun\Docker\ContainerDockerCompose\sharedDataInput:/sharedDataInput:rw'

ERROR: for webapp  Cannot create container for service webapp: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Fun\Docker\ContainerDockerCompose\sharedDataInput:/sharedDataInput:rw'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**also try this**
switch to linux conteiners and set settings and back to windows conteiners but also not help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the folders sharedDataInput and sharedDataOutput in ./ and gave them correct permissions? (usually 775)

It sounds like your build isn't finding the folders.

Comment: In my content folder I have this folders and later they are in container

Answer (score 0):

correct answer :) you can not mount volumes in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ even you make this correct hehehehe :)

docker-compose (correct code + added .env file)

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  webapp:  
    container_name: Main_Server_1
    build: main/.
    volumes:
       - .\sharedDataInput:C:\App\sharedDataInput
       - .\sharedDataOutput:C:\App\sharedDataOutput
    ports:
       - "8200:80"
```

dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY content ./
RUN powershell New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\App\sharedDataInput
RUN powershell New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\App\sharedDataOutput
RUN icacls C:\App\* /grant Everyone:F
RUN icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\* /grant Everyone:F
```

docker.env

```
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```